# Get and Set values of properties generic type

Tags: c#, generics, properties

I am actually struggling with generics :)

How can I access properties of a type passed as generic into a method? Do I need to use reflection in any case?

For example the following class

```
public class someClassA()
{
    public int attributeA1;
    public string attributeA2;
{

public class someClassB()
{
public int attributeB1;
public string attributeB2;
{


// Then a generic method
private TItem GetSomeData<TItem>(Guid Id) where TItem: new()
    {
        TItem instanceOfClass = new TItem();
        // doing some data stuff
        // ....
        // finally group the result for better iteration
        var groupedById = result.ToList().GroupBy(x =>
                                (x["SomeId"]))
                                .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                                .ToList();

        foreach (var item in groupedById)
        {
            // how can I access and set the properties of TItem -> instanceOfClass?
            instanceOfClass.... = item.property1;
            instanceOfClass.... = item.property2;
            ....
        }

        return instanceOfClass;
    }
```

The above method is called like this for example

```
var data = GetSomeData<someClassA>(someId)
```

Any hint or advice is higly appreciated!

I have already tried with reflection but I am unsure wether this is usefull or not.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve, but what you are trying doesn't really look that generic to me. If your "generic" method needs to access properties with different names declared by different types, then it is not really generic but rather specific (i.e., it's implementation logic depending on whether it works with someClassA vs. someClassB)

Comment: "how can I access and set the properties of TItem " in short: you cannot! unless you constraint the generic parameter to implement a certain interface or inherit from a certain class. Research "generic constraint"

Comment: you both are right...thank you for the hints :)

Comment: As i know you can't do that without casting or something, because your method that takes a generic type does not know the generic type you feed with. So either you try to find out which type the generic type is or you make a base-class for both classes, that implement them. But like @elgonzo mentioned, it would not be very generic